# Complicated SQL query vs datatable iteration and proccessing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a three table structure in SQL Server 2012: people, connections and messages. The affected schema would be like this:

**People**: Id (pk bigint), name...
**Connections**: Id (pk bigint), IdPpl1 fk, IdPpl2 fk
**Messages**: Id (pk uniqueidentifier), Idconnection (fk), Messagetype (smallint)

On the Connections table, IdPpl1 and IdPpl2 are fk's to people Id. It could happen to appear in this table the same "two people" but swapping their column, E.G:

```
Id IdPpl1 IdPpl2  
.. ...... ......  
3     101    105  
8     105    101
9     101    106
10    106    101
```

The above situation is correct. Actually, those are the maximum occurrences of these "two people" in the table.

The Messages table holds the information of which "connection" sent a message.

```
Id IdConnection Messagetype
.. ............ ...........
24            3           1
25            8           1
26            3           2
27            8           2
28            9           3
29           10           2
```

(*Note: the messages are one-way, that's why there can be two rows in the connections table affecting the same two people: on the first row, one person is the sender and the other the receiver, on the second row they swap)*

Given a People Id, I need a SQL query to show "least connectiontype messages mutually sent by mutually connected people" and an extra colum indicating if the messagetype matches or not. The result should be like this, for **People Id 101:**

```
Person_id Person_name IdConnection MatchingMsgType
......... ........... ............ ...............
      105        John            3               1 
      106       Peter            9               0
```

The first row appears because of MsgIds 24 and 25. A potential row corresponding with messages 26 and 27 won't appear because a previous matching messagetype was found.
The second row appears because of  MsgIds 28 and 29, marking the messagetype as non-matching.

Currently I get all the "messages related to a person" and iterate through the datatable sorting, filtering and operating in-memory.

Would you go with a full-SQL solution (I want to preserve full isolation between app tiers) or is more suitable the datatable iteration?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it depends on the length of the resulting set of your current db query (the one resulting in all rows related to a user). It is not clear if rows are ever removed from you tables. If not, your solution does not scale, since the number of matching rows will grow for ever. If instead you can assert the the number of resulting rows has some bound (for example: the maximum number of connections a user can open at the same time) then your solution might be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for your input @manu-fatto: the row count should be no more than 300 rows in the worst case, and no: rows are not removed!